# yup - is there any way to set the default value for a string field to be something without defining it for each one

Tags: yup

I want that every time I use `yup.string()`, it will add a specific default value for it

for example:

```
const schema =  yup.object({
    text: yup.string()// I want it to also do .default('some string') in the background,
});
```

or - another option - is there any way to set the default value after creating the scheme? something like `setDefault('text', 'some string')`

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I came across to solve your issue is extending your `string` with a **custom method** that implements your needs. To do that you need to use `addMethod` from `yup`:

```js
import { addMethod, string } from 'yup';

addMethod(string, 'append', function append(appendStr) {
  return this.transform((value) => `${value}${appendStr}`);
});
```

Now, you can use your **custom method (`append`)** and apply it to any `string` you want:

```js
string().append('~~~~').cast('hi'); // 'hi~~~~'
```

If you want to add the **custom method** to all your `schema` types like `date`, `number`, etc..., you need to extend the abstract base class `Schema`:

```js
import { addMethod, Schema } from 'yup';

addMethod(Schema, 'myCustomMethod', ...)
```

### Extra

#### For `Typescript`

In your `type definition` file, you need to `declare module yup` with your **custom method**'s `arguments` and `return` types:

```js
// globals.d.ts
import { StringSchema } from "yup";

declare module 'yup' {
  interface StringSchema<TType, TContext, TDefault, TFlags> {
    append(appendStr: string): this;
  }
}
```

#### Unknow behavior for `transform` method

While I was trying to extend the functionality of the `date` schema with a **custom method that `transform` the date that user enters from `DD-MM-YYY` to `YYYY-MM-DD`**, the **custom method** broke after I used it with **other methods** like `min`, `max` for example.

```js
// `dayMonthYear` should transform "31-12-2022"
// to "2022-12-31" but for some reason it kept
// ignoring the `cast` date and tried to transform
// `1900` instead!
Yup.date().dayMonthYear().min(1900).max(2100).required().cast("31-12-2022") // error
```

To work around this issue, I appended my **custom method** at the end of my schema chain:

```js
Yup.date().min(1900).max(2100).required().cast("31-12-2022").dayMonthYear() // works as expected
```

This issue is mentioned in [this GH ticket](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/312#issuecomment-442854307) which I recommend going through it as it's going more in-depth on how to add **custom methods** with `Typescript`.

#### References

- [`addMethod`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#addmethodschematype-schema-name-string-method--schema-void)
- [Extending built-in schema with new methods](https://github.com/jquense/yup#extending-built-in-schema-with-new-methods)
- [Example of `addMethod` in Typescript (GH ticket)](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/312)